# AzCosmosDBSqlRoleAssignment issue for a group

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-identity

We have an AzureGroup, say `CMR`, & it has `> 400 members`. I want to give a `cosmosDB permission` for each member of the group. `Azure AD identity (which could be a user, security group, service principal, or managed identity)` for `CMR` can be used for giving access to each member of the group.

For that I have used `AzCosmosDBSqlRoleAssignment` and ran the following command for the `principalID` for the `CMR` whose `principlaid` is `9f58c295-efa6-4513-84c6-9c84d4033396`

```
$resourceGroupName = "test"
$accountName = "test7782"
$contributorRoleDefinitionId = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"
$principalId = "9f58c295-efa6-4513-84c6-9c84d4033396"
New-AzCosmosDBSqlRoleAssignment -AccountName $accountName `
-ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
-RoleDefinitionId $contributorRoleDefinitionId `
-Scope "/" `
-PrincipalId $principalId
```

Please note, I'm using `contributorRoleDefinitionId` as `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001` which has `readMetadata` permission.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac :

[image]

The command ran fine. But then I used Python API to establish connection with the database and getting permission error.

```
# Azure Identity library provides Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) token authentication support across the Azure SDK.
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.azureclicredential?view=azure-dotnet
from azure.identity.aio import AzureCliCredential    
azure_credential = AzureCliCredential()
```

I'm getting following error:

```
Request is blocked because principal [9f58c295-efa6-4513-84c6-9c84d4033396] does not have required RBAC permissions to perform action [Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readMetadata] on resource [dbs/].
```

It works perfectly when I switch to giving permissions for `each member of the group` of `CMR` with their `principalid`. But that is cumbersome and way more difficult for me to manage. Any help/suggestions on how to make the it work giving group permission?

Comment: can you confirm the principal with id `9f58c295-efa6-4513-84c6-9c84d4033396` is in the group CRM ?

Comment: yes correct.  When I visited the `CRM group page in Azure portal`, it is the `object Id` for the group => the `principalid` I used. All users are part of the group. When I give the user's `principalid`  for `New-AzCosmosDBSqlRoleAssignment` , it works. But group level authorization seems not sticking. Not sure it is an issue with `AzureCliCredential` but the error message is loud and clear that `AzureCliCredential ` tried but Azure blocked it.

Comment: Firstly, if each individual member in the group has to access the account, you need to provide the permissions to each member separately in the group. Or try creating a role definition using `New-AzCosmosDBSqlRoleDefinition` first and assign role to the account using `New-AzRoleAssignment -objectId ""`. Did you try this way? @DibyenduDey

Comment: @Jahnavi the point of giving permission to the group is to avoid having to grant individual permission... And from Azure AD perspective that should work.

Comment: Can you try giving role assignment with `New-AzRoleAssignment  -Scope "Cosmosaccount resource ID"` command with the role definition ID and group object ID.  [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azroleassignment?view=azps-10.3.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-9.0.1). @DibyenduDey

Comment: @Jahnavi 1) role definition id can be defined or alread-defined role definition can be used. I'm using `built-in role definition` from Azure https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac#built-in-role-definitions =>  `RoleDefinitionId 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001` which is good enough for my used case (read permission for users). 2) scope can be `account-level/database level/Container level`. I have given `account level` which is higest level one can give. Think issue is `azure_credential = AzureCliCredential()` is pulling `AAD` token which is missing something!

Comment: I could finally make it work switching to a different group. The difference between `successful group` and `unsuccessful group` is currently under investigation. Successful group is made via `Microsoft Identity manager` instead of making it directly in `Azure AD`.  https://idweb.microsoft.com/IdentityManagement/default.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My method was correct but I was giving access to the `principalid` of `M365` group, instead of `Mail-enabeled security groups`. `M365 group` seems will never work for giving `bulk access to CosmosDB RBAC` . Whereas `Windows Server AD` which was successful, as this is made via `Microsoft Identify Manager (MIM)` https://idweb.microsoft.com/IdentityManagement/default.aspx:

[image]

## Further Research:

There are many different ways of group formation:

[image]

### Microsoft M365 Group

`M365` group seems used for collaboration between inside & outside of company. For this security reason, `M365` group's each member needs to be provided access to lower-level resources like `CosmosDB read permission`.

### Microsoft Identify Manager (MIM)

Microsoft Identity Manager (MIM) is a service that allows you to manage your organization’s users, credentials, and devices. My Laptop needs to be in `my company VPN` to even access the MIM group. For this extra security, no further low level access is required for individual users.